# Angular - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'. 103 event.preventDefault;

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11 project, I have this code:

```js
logout(Event = MouseEvent){
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
  event.preventDefault;
  this.loggedIn = false;
  this.token.remove();
  this.auth.changeAuthStatus(false);
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  this.notify.info("Logout Succesfully", {timeout:2000});
}
```

And I got this error:

> error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.  103 event.preventDefault;
> 'event' is deprecated

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function declaration contains errors:

- you named your parameter `Event` but you're referencing `event` inside your function body
- you assign the `MouseEvent` type as value to the variable instead of declaring it as a type

The correct function declaration should be something like this:

```
logout($event: MouseEvent){
  $event.preventDefault();
  // the rest of your business logic...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing parentheses.

```
event.preventDefault();
```